# HTML::Template <TMPL_IF> blocks being skipped

Tags: html, perl, templates

I'm having trouble getting [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Template/)'s `<TMPL_IF>` blocks to function -- it seems like my template is just skipping that code entirely.

```
  <TMPL_LOOP NAME=DATA>
    <TMPL_VAR NAME=complete><br>
    <TMPL_IF NAME="complete">
                    <!-- Some HTML here -->
    <TMPLE_ELSE>
        <!-- Some other HTML here -->
    </TMPL_IF>
  </TMPL_LOOP>
```

The `TMPL_VAR` line is displaying the expected values, but nothing in the block below it is showing up whatsoever.  The data structure I'm passing in to the template is:

```
    $VAR1 = [
      {
        'code' => 26,
        'message' => 'Start building sensors for Jarvis',
        'complete' => 0
      },
      {
        'code' => 33,
        'message' => 'Machine learning to determine if actions are appropriate or not',
        'complete' => 0
      },
      {
        'code' => 37,
        'message' => 'Play by genre audioserv method',
        'complete' => 0
      }
    ];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated -- I've been banging my head against it for the last hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Template/lib/HTML/Template.pm#TMPL_IF):

> The `<TMPL_IF>` tag allows you to include or not include a block of the template based on the value of a given parameter name. If the parameter is given a value that is true for Perl - like '1' - then the block is included in the output. If it is not defined, or given a false value - like '0' - then it is skipped.

All your `complete`s are zero so `<TMPL_IF>` won't show anything. You might expect the "else" branch to be displayed but you don't have any [`<TMPL_ELSE>`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Template/lib/HTML/Template.pm#TMPL_ELSE) branches, you have `<TMPLE_ELSE>`. Fix the typo and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that about 10 minutes ago, and it does indeed work now. I think I either need more sleep or more caffeine.

Comment: @mydnight: I'd recommend more sleep :)